# Cannot log in MySQL (in a Docker container)

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL installed in a Docker container and I'm tying to log in and it just won't accept my credentials.

I'm careful to copy paste my password.

I retyped everything fearing some hidden character somewhere... no luck.

```
mysql> use mysql;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> grant all privileges on db_thalasoft.* to thalasoft@'%' identified by 'XXX';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> quit;
Bye
root@89b59e4faab5:/usr/bin/mysql/install# bin/mysql -u thalasoft -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'thalasoft'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The version is a self built one from the `mysql-5.6.30.tar.gz` archive.

Comment: What is the command you used to start the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR**: wild card `%` does not include special host `localhost`.

You need to create a login for the special host `localhost` to indicate a login from the local host (from the MySQL server point of view). The `%` is a wild card for IP addresses in case you are using an IP to connect to the host (or force the access via TCP with the `--protocol=tcp` option). So when you connect via local sockets (which will be used when you don't provide a host in the command line) you must have a user which is configured for the `localhost` host. See [6.2.3 Specifying Account Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html):

> A host value can be a host name or an IP address (IPv4 or IPv6). The name `'localhost'` indicates the local host. The IP address `'127.0.0.1'` indicates the IPv4 loopback interface. The IP address `'::1'` indicates the IPv6 loopback interface.

Comment: Indeed I can log in with the MySQL client just fine if using the tcp protocol `root@952fbb1e6c9e:/usr/bin/mysql/install# /usr/bin/mysql/install/bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h mysql -P 3306 -u thalasoft -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.`. I shall investigate if the PHP client in a Docker container uses the TCP protocol by default.